# Get JpegImage.aspx captcha from URL in android

Tags: java, android-studio, jsoup, captcha

I am relatively new to programming. I need to fill a form on a url through an Android APP with:

1. `Dropdown` menu
2. `TextField`
3. Captacha (`Image` and `TextField`)

I will use post requests through JSOUP for 1 and 2.

For 3:
I have gone through the html of the page and the captcha image seems like this:

```
img id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_capchaImage" src="JpegImage.aspx" 
style="height:50px;width:100%;"
```

I'm currently able to get captcha image url but unable to display it in Android ImageView. Following is my code:

```
try {
                Bitmap captchaimg = null;
                String B = "https://whatever.com";

                Document doc2 = Jsoup.connect(B).get();
                Element captcha = doc2.select("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_capchaImage").first();

                imgsrc = captcha.attr("abs:src");
                System.out.println("\nsrc : " + imgsrc);
                InputStream inputStream = new URL(imgsrc).openStream();
                captchaimg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

} 
catch (IOException e) 
{
            builder.append("Error : ").append(e.getMessage()).append("\n");
}

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
{
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    imagev.setImageBitmap(captchaimg);
});
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTyTT.png) is the problem that I am actually having.

P.S. The source code of the aspx captcha is given on this site [CAPTCHA](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5947/CAPTCHA-Image-2#_comments)

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @TDG I have updated my answer according to what I've currently done.